# How to add borderWidth to card in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm making an android application in react native in which i have a layout which contains `textinput` and a `picker`.

The `picker` is inside card which I imported from native base. When I gave borderWidth to `textinput` or nay other view it works ,but borderaWidth doesn't works in Card.Why ?

I gave card borderwidth to card but it doesn't works ? Whether i keep borderwidth to 2 or 20 nothing works.This is very important for my project please give me solution to add borderWidth to card.

Card supports borderWidth or not ?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: What is the Card? A component? Looks through the component and see what props it takes - if it even takes style as a prop. Otherwise, wrap it around a view and set border to the view

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your card with `<View>` and give border to this view.

like this,

```
<View 
    style={{
     borderWidth:2,
     borderColor:"#000000"
    }}
>
 //your cards here
</View>
```